# SVG takes up too much space

Tags: html, css, svg

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NPyxMg

My SVG has a huge spacing in all directions around it. I want the space to the right and left but top and bottom are too much. How do I get it to behave? The style sheet is in the codepen.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Empowering PA Youth</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="empower.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <div id="empowering">
            <script language="javascript">
                function toggle() {
                    var text1 = document.getElementById("refresh");
                    var text2 = document.getElementById("revive");
                    var text3 = document.getElementById("renew");
                    var ele1 = document.getElementById("g3829");
                    if (text1.style.display == "block") {
                        text1.style.display = "none";
                        text2.style.display = "none";
                        text3.style.display = "none";
                    }
                    else {
                        text1.style.display = "block";
                        text2.style.display = "none";
                        text3.style.display = "none";
                    }
                }
                function toggle2() {
                    var text1 = document.getElementById("refresh");
                    var text2 = document.getElementById("revive");
                    var text3 = document.getElementById("renew");
                    var ele2 = document.getElementById("g3838");
                    if (text2.style.display == "block") {
                        text1.style.display = "none";
                        text2.style.display = "none";
                        text3.style.display = "none";
                    }
                    else {
                        text2.style.display = "block";
                        text1.style.display = "none";
                        text3.style.display = "none";
                    }
                }
                function toggle3() {
                    var text1 = document.getElementById("refresh");
                    var text2 = document.getElementById("revive");
                    var text3 = document.getElementById("renew");
                    var ele3 = document.getElementById("g3846");
                    if (text3.style.display == "block") {
                        text1.style.display = "none";
                        text2.style.display = "none";
                        text3.style.display = "none";
                    }
                    else {
                        text1.style.display = "none";
                        text2.style.display = "none";
                        text3.style.display = "block";
                    }
                }
            </script>

            <svg
                xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
                version="1.1"
                id="Layer_1"
                viewBox="0 0 600 400"
                PreserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet"
                >
            <path
                style="fill:#c9cdd3"
                id="path3646"
                d="m 300.019,198.427 c -0.021,0.021 0.005,0.037 0.052,0.053 -0.014,-0.049 -0.03,-0.076 -0.052,-0.053 z" /><path
                style="opacity:0.6;fill:#c9cdd3"
                id="path3648"
                d="m 425.283,215.57 1.148,0.025 0,-1.412 -1.148,0.041 0.019,-1.127 -1.083,-0.021 0,-2.848 -0.682,-0.052 -0.055,-0.786 -1.808,-0.42 0.068,-0.782 1.007,0.021 0.025,-0.524 0.682,-0.236 0.157,-0.656 0.63,-0.184 -0.498,-4.826 c 0,0 2.309,-2.702 2.229,-2.702 -0.08,0 -1.392,-1.677 -1.392,-1.677 l -1.285,1.049 -1.415,-2.746 -1.259,0 -0.908,-1.216 0.735,-0.812 0.078,-1.234 1.337,-0.183 -1.23,-0.366 1.23,-0.735 -1.6,-0.053 0.918,-1.075 -1.495,0.761 -0.13,-1.364 -0.63,1.285 -0.42,-0.026 -0.891,-0.734 0.444,1.285 -0.945,-0.131 0,-0.954 -0.224,-0.122 -0.091,-3.486 -0.589,-0.824 0.013,-0.173 1.075,-0.026 0,-0.97 -0.262,-0.343 -0.788,-0.051 -0.078,-0.285 0.866,-0.108 0,-0.786 -0.289,-0.457 -0.025,-0.384 -0.315,-0.366 0.45,-0.943 0,-0.684 -1.814,2.377 0,0.981 0.314,0.37 0.079,0.233 -0.315,0 -0.314,0.419 0,1.049 0.473,0.262 0.003,1.212 0.603,0 0,1.222 -0.972,4.427 0,1.759 0.555,0.464 0,1.944 0.471,1.008 -0.471,2.604 0,1.02 0.535,0 0.092,0.487 -0.069,2.105 0.417,0 0.016,2.32 -0.433,1.66 0,4.861 -0.904,-0.02 0,1.287 -1.271,-0.014 0.281,1.555 1.073,-0.008 -1.213,2.27 c 0,0 -0.565,-4.1 -5.23,-6.645 -0.429,-0.232 -0.852,-0.426 -1.27,-0.602 -2.126,-2.615 -6.149,-2.131 -6.149,-2.131 l 0,-2.094 -0.844,0.26 c -0.249,-0.891 -0.706,-1.365 -1.111,-1.619 l 0,-14.644 -5.249,0 0,10.794 -0.36,0 0,4.531 -0.204,0.203 -1.417,0 0,-41.742 -6.655,-0.082 0,33.616 c -0.657,0.089 -1.244,0.311 -1.727,0.562 l 0,-30.563 -4.889,-4.889 -5.875,4.812 0.075,26.259 c -0.882,-0.108 -1.658,0.018 -2.318,0.259 l 0,-49.52 -3.285,-0.04 -0.057,-0.68 2.564,0.021 0.777,-0.361 0,-0.565 -0.624,-0.51 -2.773,-0.055 -0.453,-19.192 -0.48,19.196 -2.916,0 -0.624,0.447 0.058,0.679 0.679,0.341 2.804,0 0,0.545 -3.774,0 0,47.603 -1.395,-1.193 -2.261,2.544 0,3.109 -0.707,0 0,7.351 -0.707,0 0,3.295 -1.514,0 0,-17.146 -1.598,0 0,-5.257 -3.069,0 0,5.257 -0.398,0 0,4.726 -4.792,0 0,0.781 c -0.65,-0.009 -1.067,-0.016 -1.067,-0.016 l 0,0.264 -0.42,0 0,-3.476 -0.871,0 0,-1.638 -6.058,0 0,8.025 -2.211,0 0,6.457 -1.102,0 0,-1.171 -1.872,0 0,-0.77 -0.88,0 0,-1.102 -1.103,0 0,3.042 -0.749,0 0,-5.655 -1.556,-9.469 -1.556,9.469 0,5.373 -0.534,0.133 0,-17.007 -8.102,0 0,3.431 -1.16,0 0,6.874 -0.358,0 -0.588,-2.781 -0.754,2.781 -2.046,0 c 0,-2.781 0,-6.323 0,-6.323 l -1.541,0 0,1.321 -4.405,0 0,-0.991 -2.092,0 0,1.432 -1.544,0 0,-1.102 -1.65,0 0,5.729 c -0.81,0.033 -1.715,0.051 -1.939,-0.014 0.127,0.438 -0.052,3.485 -0.052,3.485 l -1.22,0 0,3.738 -0.991,0 0,-5.938 -1.13,-2.119 -1.132,2.543 0,4.241 -0.837,0 0,-15.6 -5.821,0 0,2.501 -0.646,0 0,5.365 -2.091,0 0,-7.566 -3.712,0 0,-6.083 -4.72,0 0,3 -4.564,0 0,11.882 -0.436,0 0,4.876 -0.428,0.428 0,-37.29 -0.865,0 0,-6.137 -0.865,0 0,-2.594 -0.865,0 0,-1.024 -0.944,0 0,-1.416 -0.787,0.158 0,-0.707 -0.471,-0.079 c 0,0 -0.044,-5.979 0,-7.079 0.048,-1.233 -1.245,-1.351 -1.245,-1.351 l 0,-3.133 -0.394,0 0,3.106 c -1.515,0.056 -1.588,1.22 -1.588,1.22 l 0,7.864 -1.179,0 0,1.259 -0.943,0 0,1.259 -0.944,0.08 0,2.201 -0.707,0.078 0,6.214 -0.474,0 0,31.276 -0.727,0.58 0,0.635 c -0.043,0 -0.073,-0.002 -0.073,-0.002 l 0,1.792 -1.021,0 0,-17.621 -4.821,0 0,18.942 -0.208,0 -2.262,-2.262 0,-13.376 0,-1.982 -1.432,0 0,-1.322 -3.768,0 0,-8.898 -3.343,0 0,18.367 -3.121,0 0,-15.518 -4.054,0 0,23.67 -1.022,0 0,-1.432 -1.663,0.079 0,-1.994 -0.1,0 0,-1.279 -1.541,0 0,-1.102 -0.494,0 0,-10.492 -5.588,0 0,9.611 -1.096,0 0,-9.611 -5.016,0 0,7.959 -1.574,0 0,3.267 -0.564,-0.331 -0.707,0.827 0,1.292 -0.706,0.142 0,7.058 -1.11,0 0,-22.362 -0.478,-0.478 0,-2.457 -0.957,-0.958 0,-5.628 -1.345,-1.292 0,-1.757 -0.206,-0.259 0,-1.447 -0.361,-0.31 0,-1.86 -0.518,-0.102 0,-1.861 -0.205,-0.154 0,-1.189 -0.312,-0.259 0,-1.084 -0.412,-0.879 -0.013,-8.377 0,0.155 -0.195,8.222 -0.259,0 0,1.551 -0.749,1.602 0,1.37 -0.8,0.799 0,1.758 -0.529,0 0,1.898 -0.375,0.376 0,1.524 -0.285,0.283 0,1.602 -0.305,0 0,5.491 -0.766,0 0,1.405 -0.894,0 0,23.698 -1.083,0 0,-1.273 -0.624,0 0,-11.73 -10.114,0 0,14.863 c -0.79,0.049 -1.561,0.044 -1.561,-0.164 0,0.102 0,1.025 0,2.229 l -0.439,0.439 0,-7.378 -2.863,0 0,7.679 -1.433,0 0,-9.552 -6.718,0 0,13.058 -1.708,0 0,-6.725 -6.627,0 0,4.757 0,12.763 258.243,-0.166 c 0.055,-5.089 -3.833,-6.386 -3.833,-6.386 z" /></g></g><a
                id="a3853"
                class="blueleaf"
                xlink:href="http://www.harmonyheartcamp.org"><path
                    d="m 219.686,191.798 c 0,0 13.039,-3.188 24.201,-1.241 11.163,1.947 35.141,-1.469 34.718,-22.108 0,0 3.104,-1.351 5.837,-0.694 -3.862,-1.792 -23.657,-7.482 -37.504,4.148 0,0 6.014,-12.095 30.06,-8.237 0,0 -10.173,-12.876 -25.449,-7.801 -15.278,5.075 -21.789,29.058 -31.863,35.933 z"
                    id="blue"
                    style="fill:#0088c3" /></a><a
                id="a3856"
                xlink:href="http://www.campcomanche.org"><path
                    d="m 254.149,107.082 c 0,0 5.698,12.154 5.99,23.48 0.294,11.327 8.377,34.159 28.525,29.674 0,0 1.938,2.776 1.834,5.584 0.992,-4.141 2.667,-24.668 -11.467,-35.948 0,0 13.041,3.509 14.005,27.844 0,0 10.616,-12.515 2.626,-26.488 -7.99,-13.974 -32.785,-15.626 -41.513,-24.146 z"
                    id="green"
                    style="fill:#97c25f" /></a><a
                id="a3870"
                xlink:href="http://www.stpaulshouse.org"><path
                    d="m 380.314,191.798 c 0,0 -13.039,-3.188 -24.201,-1.241 -11.163,1.947 -35.141,-1.469 -34.718,-22.108 0,0 -3.104,-1.351 -5.837,-0.694 3.862,-1.792 23.657,-7.482 37.504,4.148 0,0 -6.014,-12.095 -30.059,-8.237 0,0 10.173,-12.876 25.448,-7.801 15.278,5.075 21.79,29.058 31.863,35.933 z"
                    id="orange"
                    style="fill:#f08c3c" /></a><a
                id="a3859"
                xlink:href="http://www.campcomanche.org"><path
                    d="m 345.851,107.082 c 0,0 -5.698,12.154 -5.99,23.48 -0.294,11.327 -8.377,34.159 -28.524,29.674 0,0 -1.938,2.776 -1.835,5.584 -0.993,-4.141 -2.667,-24.668 11.467,-35.948 0,0 -13.041,3.509 -14.005,27.844 0,0 -10.615,-12.515 -2.626,-26.488 7.991,-13.974 32.785,-15.626 41.513,-24.146 z"
                    id="yellow"
                    style="fill:#fde33b" /></a><path
                d="m 287.124,222.00999 28.294,0 c 0,0 -17.034,-11.39802 -7.268,-53.01 0,0 -1.939,3.14001 -2.814,2.74864 -2.627,-1.4035 -0.908,-12.81963 -0.908,-12.81963 0,0 -2.464,9.55788 -5.025,9.88486 -2.562,0.32497 -5.253,-9.81846 -5.253,-9.81846 0,0 2.756,14.80868 -0.128,14.64468 -1.381,-0.0533 -2.271,-0.64993 -2.271,-0.64993 0,0 12.98,23.57174 -4.627,49.01984 z"
                id="path3664"
                style="fill:#846541" /><g
                id="g3666"><g
                id="g3668"><path
                id="path3670"
                d="m 169.602,228.112 22.285,0 0,7.603 -14.57,0 0,7.383 14.57,0 0,7.465 -14.57,0 0,10.74 14.57,0 0,7.631 -22.285,0 0,-40.822 z" /><path
                id="path3672"
                d="m 201.953,228.112 7.57,0 9.463,28.472 9.549,-28.472 7.566,0 6.848,40.821 -7.514,0 -4.377,-25.781 -8.674,25.781 -6.848,0 -8.596,-25.781 -4.48,25.781 -7.576,0 7.069,-40.821 z" /><path
                id="path3674"
                d="m 247.973,228.112 8.242,0 c 4.459,0 7.674,0.411 9.643,1.235 1.971,0.822 3.525,2.154 4.662,3.996 1.139,1.84 1.707,4.047 1.707,6.618 0,2.85 -0.744,5.217 -2.234,7.104 -1.488,1.887 -3.51,3.199 -6.062,3.939 -1.498,0.426 -4.229,0.64 -8.188,0.64 l 0,17.288 -7.77,0 0,-40.82 z m 7.769,15.956 2.471,0 c 1.943,0 3.293,-0.139 4.051,-0.418 0.76,-0.277 1.355,-0.736 1.791,-1.377 0.434,-0.641 0.652,-1.416 0.652,-2.326 0,-1.576 -0.611,-2.729 -1.832,-3.451 -0.889,-0.539 -2.535,-0.809 -4.939,-0.809 l -2.193,0 0,8.381 z" /><path
                id="path3676"
                d="m 297.969,227.086 c 5.775,0 10.74,2.091 14.896,6.271 4.156,4.18 6.234,9.277 6.234,15.291 0,5.956 -2.051,10.997 -6.15,15.123 -4.102,4.127 -9.076,6.189 -14.926,6.189 -6.127,0 -11.219,-2.118 -15.273,-6.356 -4.055,-4.235 -6.08,-9.269 -6.08,-15.097 0,-3.903 0.943,-7.492 2.832,-10.766 1.889,-3.275 4.484,-5.869 7.789,-7.785 3.305,-1.913 6.863,-2.87 10.678,-2.87 z m -0.084,7.602 c -3.779,0 -6.955,1.313 -9.529,3.94 -2.574,2.627 -3.861,5.967 -3.861,10.02 0,4.514 1.621,8.084 4.861,10.711 2.52,2.053 5.408,3.08 8.668,3.08 3.686,0 6.824,-1.332 9.416,-3.995 2.594,-2.665 3.891,-5.948 3.891,-9.852 0,-3.886 -1.307,-7.175 -3.918,-9.866 -2.611,-2.691 -5.788,-4.038 -9.528,-4.038 z" /><path
                id="path3678"
                d="m 322.195,228.112 7.645,0 5.898,26.058 7.287,-26.058 6.463,0 7.396,26.058 5.842,-26.058 7.645,0 -9.197,40.821 -7.453,0 -7.521,-26.391 -7.381,26.391 -7.383,0 -9.241,-40.821 z" /><path
                id="path3680"
                d="m 375.324,228.112 22.285,0 0,7.603 -14.57,0 0,7.383 14.57,0 0,7.465 -14.57,0 0,10.74 14.57,0 0,7.631 -22.285,0 0,-40.822 z" /><path
                id="path3682"
                d="m 404.242,228.112 8.232,0 c 4.51,0 7.721,0.401 9.633,1.206 1.912,0.805 3.451,2.143 4.615,4.011 1.164,1.868 1.746,4.08 1.746,6.633 0,2.683 -0.643,4.925 -1.928,6.729 -1.287,1.804 -3.225,3.169 -5.814,4.094 l 9.672,18.148 -8.494,0 -9.18,-17.288 -0.711,0 0,17.288 -7.771,0 0,-40.821 z m 7.772,15.956 2.434,0 c 2.471,0 4.174,-0.324 5.104,-0.974 0.932,-0.649 1.398,-1.728 1.398,-3.229 0,-0.891 -0.23,-1.666 -0.691,-2.326 -0.463,-0.658 -1.08,-1.131 -1.854,-1.42 -0.775,-0.287 -2.195,-0.432 -4.262,-0.432 l -2.129,0 0,8.381 z" /></g></g>
            <a id="g3829" xlink:href="javascript:toggle();" ><path
                    d="m 188.678,276.656 2.551,0 c 1.42,0 2.383,0.059 2.889,0.174 0.76,0.176 1.377,0.549 1.854,1.121 0.475,0.57 0.713,1.275 0.713,2.111 0,0.698 -0.164,1.311 -0.492,1.838 -0.328,0.529 -0.795,0.929 -1.404,1.199 -0.609,0.27 -1.451,0.408 -2.523,0.414 l 4.602,5.941 -1.582,0 -4.602,-5.941 -0.725,0 0,5.941 -1.279,0 0,-12.798 z m 1.279,1.254 0,4.351 2.205,0.017 c 0.854,0 1.486,-0.082 1.896,-0.244 0.408,-0.162 0.729,-0.421 0.957,-0.777 0.23,-0.357 0.346,-0.756 0.346,-1.197 0,-0.43 -0.117,-0.818 -0.35,-1.17 -0.233,-0.352 -0.537,-0.602 -0.914,-0.754 -0.379,-0.15 -1.006,-0.225 -1.883,-0.225 l -2.257,0 z"
                    id="path3688"/><path
                    d="m 199.076,276.656 7.334,0 0,1.254 -6.055,0 0,4.01 6.004,0 0,1.254 -6.004,0 0,5.029 6.004,0 0,1.252 -7.283,0 0,-12.799 z"
                    id="path3690"/><path
                    d="m 208.266,276.656 6.412,0 0,1.254 -5.135,0 0,4.01 5.135,0 0,1.254 -5.135,0 0,6.281 -1.277,0 0,-12.799 z"
                    id="path3692"/><path
                    d="m 216.617,276.656 2.549,0 c 1.422,0 2.385,0.059 2.889,0.174 0.76,0.176 1.379,0.549 1.854,1.121 0.477,0.57 0.715,1.275 0.715,2.111 0,0.698 -0.164,1.311 -0.492,1.838 -0.328,0.529 -0.797,0.929 -1.406,1.199 -0.607,0.27 -1.449,0.408 -2.521,0.414 l 4.602,5.941 -1.582,0 -4.604,-5.941 -0.723,0 0,5.941 -1.279,0 0,-12.798 z m 1.279,1.254 0,4.351 2.205,0.017 c 0.854,0 1.486,-0.082 1.895,-0.244 0.41,-0.162 0.73,-0.421 0.959,-0.777 0.23,-0.357 0.344,-0.756 0.344,-1.197 0,-0.43 -0.115,-0.818 -0.348,-1.17 -0.233,-0.352 -0.537,-0.602 -0.916,-0.754 -0.377,-0.15 -1.004,-0.225 -1.881,-0.225 l -2.258,0 z"
                    id="path3694"/><path
                    d="m 227.016,276.656 7.334,0 0,1.254 -6.055,0 0,4.01 6.004,0 0,1.254 -6.004,0 0,5.029 6.004,0 0,1.252 -7.283,0 0,-12.799 z"
                    id="path3696"/><path
                    d="m 234.881,287.072 1.088,-0.654 c 0.766,1.411 1.65,2.115 2.654,2.115 0.428,0 0.832,-0.1 1.209,-0.301 0.377,-0.199 0.664,-0.469 0.861,-0.804 0.197,-0.337 0.295,-0.694 0.295,-1.071 0,-0.429 -0.145,-0.85 -0.434,-1.262 -0.4,-0.567 -1.131,-1.252 -2.193,-2.053 -1.066,-0.807 -1.73,-1.389 -1.992,-1.748 -0.453,-0.604 -0.68,-1.256 -0.68,-1.959 0,-0.557 0.135,-1.064 0.4,-1.522 0.268,-0.458 0.643,-0.818 1.127,-1.084 0.484,-0.263 1.012,-0.396 1.58,-0.396 0.604,0 1.166,0.15 1.691,0.449 0.525,0.299 1.08,0.848 1.666,1.648 l -1.043,0.791 c -0.482,-0.637 -0.893,-1.059 -1.232,-1.261 -0.338,-0.204 -0.709,-0.306 -1.109,-0.306 -0.516,0 -0.938,0.157 -1.266,0.471 -0.328,0.312 -0.49,0.699 -0.49,1.156 0,0.279 0.057,0.549 0.174,0.811 0.115,0.26 0.326,0.545 0.635,0.852 0.168,0.164 0.719,0.59 1.652,1.279 1.109,0.818 1.869,1.546 2.279,2.185 0.412,0.638 0.619,1.278 0.619,1.923 0,0.929 -0.354,1.734 -1.059,2.418 -0.703,0.686 -1.561,1.028 -2.57,1.028 -0.777,0 -1.482,-0.208 -2.113,-0.624 -0.632,-0.413 -1.216,-1.107 -1.749,-2.081 z"
                    id="path3698"/><path
                    d="m 244.705,276.656 1.279,0 0,5.369 6.516,0 0,-5.369 1.279,0 0,12.799 -1.279,0 0,-6.177 -6.516,0 0,6.177 -1.279,0 0,-12.799 z"
                    id="path3700"/></a><path
                id="path3702"
                d="m 264.918,276.334 1.244,0 0,16.584 -1.244,0 0,-16.584 z" />
            <a id="g3838" xlink:href="javascript:toggle2();"><path
                    d="m 277.377,276.656 2.551,0 c 1.42,0 2.383,0.059 2.889,0.174 0.76,0.176 1.377,0.549 1.854,1.121 0.475,0.57 0.713,1.275 0.713,2.111 0,0.698 -0.164,1.311 -0.492,1.838 -0.328,0.529 -0.795,0.929 -1.404,1.199 -0.609,0.27 -1.451,0.408 -2.523,0.414 l 4.602,5.941 -1.582,0 -4.602,-5.941 -0.725,0 0,5.941 -1.279,0 0,-12.798 z m 1.279,1.254 0,4.351 2.205,0.017 c 0.854,0 1.486,-0.082 1.896,-0.244 0.408,-0.162 0.729,-0.421 0.957,-0.777 0.23,-0.357 0.346,-0.756 0.346,-1.197 0,-0.43 -0.117,-0.818 -0.35,-1.17 -0.233,-0.352 -0.537,-0.602 -0.914,-0.754 -0.379,-0.15 -1.006,-0.225 -1.883,-0.225 l -2.257,0 z"
                    id="path3704"
                    /><path
                    d="m 287.775,276.656 7.334,0 0,1.254 -6.055,0 0,4.01 6.004,0 0,1.254 -6.004,0 0,5.029 6.004,0 0,1.252 -7.283,0 0,-12.799 z"
                    id="path3706"
                    /><path
                    d="m 295.988,276.656 1.393,0 4.242,9.889 4.311,-9.889 1.393,0 -5.568,12.799 -0.279,0 -5.492,-12.799 z"
                    id="path3708"/><path
                    d="m 308.936,276.656 1.279,0 0,12.799 -1.279,0 0,-12.799 z"
                    id="path3710"
                    /><path
                    d="m 311.816,276.656 1.391,0 4.242,9.889 4.312,-9.889 1.391,0 -5.568,12.799 -0.277,0 -5.491,-12.799 z"
                    id="path3712"
                    /><path
                    d="m 324.955,276.656 7.334,0 0,1.254 -6.057,0 0,4.01 6.004,0 0,1.254 -6.004,0 0,5.029 6.004,0 0,1.252 -7.281,0 0,-12.799 z"
                    id="path3714"
                    /></a><path
                id="path3716"
                d="m 342.521,276.334 1.244,0 0,16.584 -1.244,0 0,-16.584 z" /><a
                id="g3846" xlink:href="javascript:toggle3();"><path
                    d="m 354.982,276.656 2.549,0 c 1.422,0 2.385,0.059 2.889,0.174 0.76,0.176 1.377,0.549 1.854,1.121 0.475,0.57 0.713,1.275 0.713,2.111 0,0.698 -0.164,1.311 -0.49,1.838 -0.328,0.529 -0.797,0.929 -1.406,1.199 -0.609,0.27 -1.449,0.408 -2.523,0.414 l 4.604,5.941 -1.582,0 -4.604,-5.941 -0.723,0 0,5.941 -1.279,0 0,-12.798 z m 1.28,1.254 0,4.351 2.205,0.017 c 0.854,0 1.484,-0.082 1.895,-0.244 0.411,-0.162 0.729,-0.421 0.959,-0.777 0.229,-0.357 0.344,-0.756 0.344,-1.197 0,-0.43 -0.115,-0.818 -0.348,-1.17 -0.233,-0.352 -0.539,-0.602 -0.916,-0.754 -0.377,-0.15 -1.006,-0.225 -1.883,-0.225 l -2.256,0 z"
                    id="path3718"
                    /><path
                    d="m 365.381,276.656 7.334,0 0,1.254 -6.057,0 0,4.01 6.004,0 0,1.254 -6.004,0 0,5.029 6.004,0 0,1.252 -7.281,0 0,-12.799 z"
                    id="path3720"
                    /><path
                    d="m 374.578,289.455 0,-12.799 0.277,0 8.518,9.811 0,-9.811 1.262,0 0,12.799 -0.287,0 -8.447,-9.691 0,9.691 -1.323,0 z"
                    id="path3722"
                    /><path
                    d="m 387.402,276.656 7.336,0 0,1.254 -6.057,0 0,4.01 6.004,0 0,1.254 -6.004,0 0,5.029 6.004,0 0,1.252 -7.283,0 0,-12.799 z"
                    id="path3724"
                    /><path
                    d="m 395.869,276.656 1.314,0 2.613,9.223 3.67,-9.223 0.266,0 3.625,9.223 2.66,-9.223 1.305,0 -3.678,12.799 -0.238,0 -3.799,-9.685 -3.871,9.685 -0.238,0 -3.629,-12.799 z"
                    id="path3726"
                    /></a>
            </svg>

        </div>
        <div class="story" id="refresh">
            <p>How many special people change
                How many lives are living strange
                Where were you when we were getting high?
                Slowly walking down the hall
                Faster than a cannon ball
                Where were you while we were getting high?

                Some day you will find me
                Caught beneath the landslide
                In a champagne supernova in the sky
                Some day you will find me
                Caught beneath the landslide
                In a champagne supernova
                A champagne supernova in the sky</p>
        </div>
        <div class="story" id="revive">
            <p>The snow glows white on the mountain tonight
                Not a footprint to be seen
                A kingdom of isolation,
                And it looks like I'm the queen.

                The wind is howling like this swirling storm inside
                Couldn't keep it in, heaven knows I tried!

                Don't let them in, don't let them see
                Be the good girl you always have to be
                Conceal, don't feel, don't let them know
                Well, now they know!</p>
        </div>
        <div class="story" id="renew">
            <p>I was staring at the sky, just looking for a star
                To pray on, or wish on, or something like that
                I was having a sweet fix of a daydream of a boy
                Whose reality I knew, was a hopeless to be had
                But then the dove of hope began its downward slope
                And I believed for a moment that my chances
                Were approaching to be grabbed
                But as it came down near, so did a weary tear
                I thought it was a bird, but it was just a paper bag

                Hunger hurts, and I want him so bad, oh it kills
                'Cause I know I'm a mess he don't wanna clean up
                I got to fold 'cause these hands are too shaky to hold
                Hunger hurts, but starving works, when it costs too much to love</p>
        </div>
        <div class="nav">
            <ul>
                <li><a id="navblue" href="#">Harmony Heart Camp</a></li>
                <li><a id="navgreen" href="#">Green</a></li>
                <li><a id="navyellow" href="#">Camp Commanche</a></li>
                <li><a id="navorange" href="#">St. Paul's House</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="mission">
            <p>
                Empower is a group of organizations that are committed to the enrichment and development of children and families. Empower's task is to provide step by step assistance, helping our children become productive members of society.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Yikes, is all this code really neccessary?

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm new. It told me that I couldn't link to codepen without including the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The real reason for all your extra whitespace is simple.  In your SVG you have specified a viewBox of "0 0 600 400" (a 600x400 area with origin at 0,0), but your drawing only occupies a much smaller region in the middle of that.

If you fix the viewBox, the graphic will conform to the size you give to the SVG.  Your unwanted whitespace will disappear.

Change

```
viewBox="0 0 600 400"
```

to

```
viewBox="169.6 107.0 261 186"
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply use negative margins.

```
#empowering {
    margin: -300px auto;
}
```

This will crop 300px from your `#empowering` container in the top and bottom directions.

Comment: it works for regular screens but loses responsiveness. I can't resize it without it clipping.

Comment: By using a percentage instead of a fixed number, I'm able to get it to work. Thank you so much.

Comment: I didn't actually look at your code, I thought the SVG's size was fixed.
But yeah, you can use any metric with that method so it's fine; just be sure to make it so it never crops _too much_